# Load a property file without using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, javabeans, ejb-3.0

I have a requirement where I have to load a property file which contains CQ5 connection details from my project and provide it as bean properties in a jar which is added in my maven dependency. My Project is using this jar to connect to CQ so I should be able to provide the CQ Connection details to that project as bean properties.
Now my project is not spring based so i cannot use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` whereas the jar added as Maven dependency is Spring based.

Is there any other way to replace value in below bean properties.

```
<bean id="slingJsonRequestor"       class="com.my.project.content.requestor.SlingRequestor">
    <constructor-arg name="suffix" value="json.js"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="resourceBlacklist" ref="slingBlacklistCache"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="url" value="${cq-url}"></property>
    <property name="urlCacId" value="${cq-url-cacid}"></property>
    <property name="urlTemplate" value="${cq-url-template}"></property>
</bean>
```

Please provide a non spring solution to achieve this.

Comment: Please help if there is any way to achieve set these properties from EJB3.0 application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do it with Maven.

[Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

You simply add a properties element and a resource element to your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <myproperty>A special value</myproperty>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/myproperties.properties</include>
        </inlcudes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Then if the text ${myproperty} is encountered in myproperties.properties maven will replace it with the property value from pom.xml(Not so different from Spring, hey?)